# How to check if a user has the most recent version of my flutter app installed

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I :

- Check if a user has the most recent version of my app installed.
- Show the user an alert with a link to the appropriate app store page.
  Ps : my app is built using **flutter**

Thank You.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/upgrade
See if this package can help.

Comment: @ASADHAMEED  do I have to create an appcast class ( like this https://github.com/larryaasen/upgrader/blob/master/lib/src/appcast.dart ) in my project in order to use it ? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This article might help
https://medium.com/swlh/update-app-flutter-402c528235e4

Comment: You can answer your own based on your implementation.